# Is there a rapid development tool or IDE for developing customized POS applications?

Tags: java, database, point-of-sale

I'm seeking a development tool/environment which will allow me to quickly develop a vertical market touch-screen POS application. I understand OJAVA is an option, but I'm looking for something with a 4GL-like programming language which I can shorten the development time.. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you finish the ERD diagram, use Spring-Roo to do the rapid prototyping.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone developing a pos application should now consider doing it either in HTML5 and JavaScript or at device level as a native app on an ipad or an android.

The HTML5 route is bar far the best as one app will run on all devices using the browser. There are a few issues such as reading credit cards and printing. Web browsers don't silent print so an applet is needed to fire the printer and thus fire a cash drawer if connected. Their are also hid device card readers that will work in the browser tho not using an ipad.

From an app point of view run all the code and storage on the device as pos needs to be fast and not dependent on a constant connection to the internet.